# Server joining domain is not creating a DNS record for the computer name

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a windows 2003 active directory domain. This was based in a single site.

This has now gone multisite and the domain controllers in the new site are using Windows 2008 R2 but the schema of the domain is still win2k3.

Sites and services is configured to ensure that servers in the new site use the correct domain controllers and replication is working correctly across the two sites.

The internal DNS for the domain is AD replicated and is replicating across both sites OK.

I then change a newly provisioned server in the new site to use the two domain controllers (2k8) in the new site as their DNS servers and they are correctly able to resolve records on the AD domains DNS servers.

However when I join the new server to the domain no A record is created for the new member server despite Dynamic updates being enabled "secure only" so I'm having to create them manually.

I suspect this might be a configuration setting on the domain somewhere which is now legacy and needs to be removed but I'm not sure where to look.

Any ideas on this or other potential causes of this symptom?

Comment: A quick question: Is the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" setting enabled in the TCP/IP properties (IPv4 and IPv6) of the NIC on the server you joined to the domain?

Comment: Yes, its a totally out of the box installation of Win 2k8 R2

Comment: Is the DHCP client service running on the server? This service is used to update the servers A record in DNS.

Comment: DHCP is only used to distribute IP's it doesn't relate to DNS registration directly. All IP's are statically assigned.

Comment: Not true. The DHCP client service is used to register and update the servers IP address in DNS. From Microsoft: Dynamic DNS registration relies on the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) client service to perform dynamic updates. When you disable or set the DHCP client service to start manually, it prevents dynamic DNS updates from occurring. Even if the client or server uses a static Internet Protocol (IP) address, the DHCP client service must be running for dynamic DNS updates to occur.

Comment: My apologies, yes DHCP client is running but I'm using static assignments. I've just figured it out though after a load of diagnostics :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer thanks all. It turns out at the point the domain controllers were added to the domain the firewall rules hadn't allowed for two way replication. That issue had been fixed but as a hangover the DNS servers will refuse new records until the DNS service is restarted. Having done that all is well again and new machines are registering DNS records.